# Is there ever any difference between using just a `foreign_key=` vs `foreign_key_id=` in Django's ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

There does not appear to be a difference between the following:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb_id=a_model_id)
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb=a_model_id)
```

Printing out the SQL that Django generates for both cases shows that it is the same. However, I haven't been able to find this officially documented anywhere, and I'm therefore concerned that there may be some case where using just `modelb` might result in something different from `modelb_id`.

I'm especially interested in someone pointing me to an official source that confirms these things are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: It's better to consider the recommendation of the authors of the framework and use model field names.

> **Database Representation**
>
> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the Car model will have a manufacturer_id column. (You can change this explicitly by specifying db_column) However, your code should never have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Model fields subclass [`django.db.models.fields.Field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py). The `Field` class has an `attname` field which is [documented internally in the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L67) as the way to resolve the attribute to use on the model object.

```
# A guide to Field parameters:
#
#   * name:      The name of the field specified in the model.
#   * attname:   The attribute to use on the model object. This is the same as
#                "name", except in the case of ForeignKeys, where "_id" is
#                appended.
#   * db_column: The db_column specified in the model (or None).
#   * column:    The database column for this field. This is the same as
#                "attname", except if db_column is specified.
#
# Code that introspects values, or does other dynamic things, should use
# attname. For example, this gets the primary key value of object "obj":
#
#     getattr(obj, opts.pk.attname)
```

As part of the execution flow to [converting the `QuerySet.filter` names in the kwargs for the compiled SQL query](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1330), the names are translated to `PathInfo` tuples containing the model fields for the respective names.

[On Line 1354 for `django.db.models.sql.query.Query`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1354), is the following line:

```
field = opts.get_field(name)
```

Now `opts` is an instance of [`django.db.models.options.Options`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/options.py#L67) and the [`get_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.3/django/db/models/options.py#L543) method delegates to `_forward_fields_map` or `fields_map` cached properties.

When you look at the implementation of those two properties, you see that they return a dictionary mapping `field.name` to `field` together with `field.attname` to `field`.

This makes it so that `modelb_id` or `modelb` resolves to the model field from either of the cached properties.

In my opinion, it doesn't matter that `modelb_id` or `modelb` is passed as a keyword argument to `QuerySet.filter`. Only that the former keyword requires knowledge of an implementation detail.

However it's better to consider the recommendation of the authors of the framework and use the model field names.